# WCF Rest WebHttpBinding Cannot Find endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

I cannot find my service endpoint after hosting it in an MVC application, when I debug I can get to the base class of the service and into the service class but after I get

> Endpoint not found.

I call https://localhost:44302/api/brokerapi/ProvideAccountHoldings/ that goes to method

```
[BrokerServiceAspect(AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
[IPLoggingAspect(AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.InstanceConstructor)]
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class BrokerAPIService : ServiceBase, IBrokerAPIService, IIPLog
{
    //log pc data
    // IPLog log = null;

    //public BrokerAPIService()
    //{
    //    IPLogUtility iplog = new IPLogUtility();
    //    log = iplog.LogIP(OperationContext.Current);
    //}
    public BrokerAPIService()
        : base()
    { }

    public IEnumerable<Domain.Model.Holding> ProvideAccountHoldings()
    {
        return DB.ProvideAccountHoldings();
    }
```

from interface

```
[ServiceContract(
SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed,
ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None)]
public interface IBrokerAPIService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [FaultContract(typeof(GeneralException))]
    IEnumerable<Holding> ProvideAccountHoldings();
```

I have even tried adding

> UriTemplate = "/ProvideTransactions"

to no avail, is there something I am missing?
Here is my Configuration

```
 <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding" bypassProxyOnLocal="false">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <!--<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />-->
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" name="AOS.BrokerAPI.WCFService.BrokerAPIService">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="brokerapi" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
      name="web" contract="AOS.BrokerAPI.WCFService.IBrokerAPIService" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehaviour"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/AOS.BrokerAPI.WCFService/BrokerAPIService/" />
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/AOS.BrokerAPI.WCFService/BrokerAPIService/" />-->
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndPointBehaviour">
      <!--<enableWebScript />-->
      <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897620/endpoint-not-found-wcf-web-service

Comment: I have checked that as well, in my post i do mention it, but I still get the same error

Comment: Wouldn't it be UriTemplate = "/ProvideAccountHoldings" ?

Comment: I have found the issue, I was putting an extra / at the end of the URL, so it was going into the correct class but because of the extra slash it was looking for something else, I am not sure on how to delete the question or close it though. Thanks for the comments.